# Likelihood ratio tests versus signed likelihood ratio tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio

What is the difference between likelihood and signed likelihood ratio tests (SLRT)? What is the use of having the "sign" function in it? 
In short, what is the advantage of having SLRT over LRT?

Reference for SLRT: 
Simple and accurate one-sided inference from signed roots of likelihood ratios
Thomas J. Diciccio, Michael A. Martin and Steven E. Stern
Canadian Journal of Statistics
Volume 29, Issue 1, pages 67–76, March 2001

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're interested in? "Signed likelihood ratio test" does not appear to be very standard terminology.

Comment: @cardinal The OP should confirm the intent, but my guess is it's probably in the sense of $\quad\quad\quad$ Barndorff-Nielsen, O.E. (1986): "Inference on full or partial parameters, based on the standardized signed log-likelihood ratio.", *Biometrika* **73**, 307–322,  $\,\,$ and  $\,\,$
Barndorff-Nielsen, O.E. (1991): "Modified signed log-likelihood ratio." *Biometrika* **78**, 557–563.

Comment: Vani, even if my guess is correct, for your question to be both clear and useful you should explain in detail what you're asking about when you say 'signed likelihood ratio tests' for the benefit of not only people who might attempt an answer, but also for other people with questions of their own.

Comment: @Glen_b I have edited the question with the changes being the fact that I have added a reference that is associated with SLRT